# Vertical space between different types of footnotes in manyfoot

Tags: manyfoot

I am using the manyfoot package to create three different types of footnotes. How can I change the vertical space between the different types of footnotes in a document?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\SetFootnoteHook{\scriptsize \setstretch{1.2}}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]

\SetFootnoteHook{\tiny}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[roman]

\begin{document}

Here\footnote{First type of footnotes.} is some text with three\footnoteA{Second type of footnotes.} different types of footnotes\footnote{Another footnote of first type.}\footnoteA{Another footnote of second type.}\footnoteB{Third type of footnotes.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each new footnote is assigned a new "insert" with the name `\footins` followed by the label; in this case, `\footinsA` and `\footinsB`.  An insert is a length, count and box with the same register value.

Normally the length `\footins` is used to store the distance above the `\footnoterule`.  For the new footnotes it is used to store the space between the groups.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\SetFootnoteHook{\scriptsize \setstretch{1.2}}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]

\SetFootnoteHook{\tiny}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[roman]

\setlength{\skip\footinsA}{0pt}
\setlength{\skip\footinsB}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Here\footnote{First type of footnotes.} is some text with three\footnoteA{Second type of footnotes.} different types of footnotes\footnote{Another footnote of first type.}\footnoteA{Another footnote of second type.}\footnoteB{Third type of footnotes.}.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]