# Reducing the space between two sets of footnotes

Tags: bigfoot

I'm using this code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{*}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\footnotesep}{5mm} %allowing some space between the line and first footnote
    % \setlength{\footskip}{0pt} %doesnt do the job
    text one\footnote{set 1}
    text two\footnoteB{set 2}
    text three\footnoteB{set 2}
\end{document}
```

to create two sets of footnotes. I also need some space between the first footnote and the footnote rule, but not between footnotes. Is this possible ?

Comment: \footnotesep is the size of a strut at the start of each footnote, so it needs to be at least as large as a \footenotesize character to have any effect.  length \footins (not to be confused with count \footins or savebox \footins) is the distance ABOVE the rule.  There is no special length for the first footnote.

Comment: I'm not sure how much my previous comment applies to bigfoot.

Comment: I think bigfoot doesnt change things much, except that \setlength{\footnotesep}{5mm} applies space above and below a footnote set, and that creates a problem when there are two footnote sets with bigfoot.

Comment: somone asked the same question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365859/vertical-space-between-different-types-of-footnotes-in-manyfoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of overkill, but this is easy to do with `reledmac`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{reledmac}
\beforenotesX[B]{0pt}
\let\footnoteruleB=\relax
\begin{document}

%Text.\footnote{Footnote.}
Text.\footnoteA{Footnote A.}
Text.\footnoteB{Footnote B.}
Text.\footnoteC{Footnote C.}
Text.\footnoteA{Footnote A.}
Text.\footnoteB{Footnote B.}
Text.\footnoteC{Footnote C.}
Text.\footnoteA{Footnote A.}
Text.\footnoteB{Footnote B.}
Text.\footnoteC{Footnote C.}

\end{document}
```

If you aren't producing a (critical) edition of a text, you might want to look at §.4.2 of the package documentation to learn how to deactivate the features you don't want or need.

Comment: I agree with the overkill, but it does the job. I saw that you can change the footnote series order, but do you know if it lets you use the order they occur in the text ?

Comment: @alfred - I'm not sure what you mean. I didn't mean to change any 'footnote series order' (change from what?) and what does 'use the order they occur in the text' mean?

Comment: By 'the order they occur in the text' I meant A B C A B C A B C, but I found a different solution to this. I will use `reledmac`later on for a critical edition.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?  I modified `\footnoterule` to add an extra 5mm.

It looks like `bigfoot` adds an extra `\haselineskip` between footnote groups.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{*}

\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@ % the \hrule is .4pt high
  \vskip 5mm}% added 5mm space
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    %\setlength{\footnotesep}{5mm} %allowing some space between the line and first footnote
    % \setlength{\footskip}{0pt} %doesnt do the job
    text one\footnote{set 1}
    text two\footnoteB{set 2}
    text three\footnoteB{set 3}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: The two footnote groups are still separated. Do you think this is the maximum it is possible to do ?

Comment: @alfred - No, but I can't make heads or tails of ether the bigfoot manual or source code.

Comment: I read somewhere there was another package with options that bigfoot recognized, but i cant remember the name. foot smth, that one could also use to create two sets of footnotes

Comment: @alfred -- `bigfoot` is built on top of and meant to supersede `manyfoot`. It does do so in most respects, but it is not a very customizable package.

Comment: I tried the manyfoot freature \ExtraParaSkip but no joy.

Comment: maybe bigfoot or manyfoot recognize footmisc options

Comment: @JohnKormylo What's funny is that in the bigfoot package documentation he uses an asterisk footnote mixed with the others ..

Comment: @alfred -- That's because the asterisk note is made via `\thanks`, which is just a regular footnote (`\let\footnote\thanks`). You can mimic this behaviour with `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`, too: just put a `\thanks{Thanks}` in your `\title{<title goes here>}` and do `\maketitle` as you regularly would. E.g., `\usepackage[para]{footmisc} ... \title{Title\thanks{Thanks}} ... \maketitle ... Text.\footnote{Footnote.}`