# Changing the distance between two sets of footnotes using manyfoot

Tags: manyfoot

I am using this code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\SelectFootnoteRule{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[roman]
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{*}

\begin{document}
    Text 1\footnote{Normal footnote 1.}.

    Text 2\footnoteA{Custom footnote 1.}.

    Text 3\footnote{Normal footnote 2.}.

    Text 4\footnoteA{Custom footnote 2.}.

\end{document}
```

and trying to eliminate the distance between the normal footnotes and the (*) footnotes. Also can I add some distance from the rule ?

Comment: After you mentioned https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365859/vertical-space-between-different-types-of-footnotes-in-manyfoot I figured out how to answer it.  The extra space answer for https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395300/reducing-the-space-between-two-sets-of-footnotes should also work here.

Comment: I tried the code there and footnotes and footnotesB are still separated by an empty line. Also the footnotes are grouped by type, is there a way to keep the normal order ?

Comment: If you don't want them grouped, just use ordinary footnotes and specify the formatting on a case by case basis.  I would define new macros like \footnoteA to handle the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `\footnoteA` to specify non-numbered symbols.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\footnoteA}[2][*]% #1 = math symbol (optional, default=*), #2 = text
{\bgroup
  \edef\thempfn{$#1$}%
  \footnote[0]{#2}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill

    Text 1\footnote{Normal footnote 1.}.

    Text 2\footnoteA{Custom footnote 1.}.

    Text 3\footnote{Normal footnote 2.}.

    Text 4\footnoteA[\dagger]{Custom footnote 2.}.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Hej, this is exactly, and I mean exactly what I needed. Many many thanks.